# Rails : Calling a function in a loop returns same value for each iteration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, loops, methods, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to calculate Leave taken by a particular student "UG10001" in a particular month from a leaves table in mysql database. I am using following snippets of code--

```
def calculate(student_id)

 leave = Leave.find_by_sql("SELECT leave_duration FROM leaves WHERE MONTH(leave_from) = 2
  AND YEAR(leave_from) = 2013 AND MONTH(leave_to) = 2 AND YEAR(leave_to) = 2013 AND
  academic_status = 'APPROVED' AND warden_status = 'APPROVED' AND student_id = student_id 
  AND status = 'ACTIVE'")

 sum = leave.sum(&:leave_duration)
 return sum

end
```

----------Update----------

```
  def calculate(student_id)

 sum = Leave.find_by_sql("SELECT leave_duration FROM leaves WHERE MONTH(leave_from) = 2
  AND YEAR(leave_from) = 2013 AND MONTH(leave_to) = 2 AND YEAR(leave_to) = 2013 AND
  academic_status = 'APPROVED' AND warden_status = 'APPROVED' AND student_id = student_id 
  AND status = 'ACTIVE'").sum(&:leave_duration)

 return sum
#it did the trick for me.
end
```

The above method will calculate the leave taken by a particular student in the month of February '13 and returns the sum of the leaves to the calling function.

```
def calcuateLeaveForEachStudent
  array = Leave.find_by_sql("select student_id from students")
  c = Array.new
  for i in 0...array.length
     student_id = array[i].student_id
     c[i] = calculate(student_id) 
  end
end
```

But when I call the above method, 'calculate' method returns the same value on each iteration. What could be the possible solution for this..? Thanks in advance..!

PS -
Code runs perfectly on Rails Console without any syntactical errors, however there is some error I can't figure out.

Comment: Correct method is  calculate(operation, column_name, options = {}). Your method is like that calculate(sum, student_id)

Comment: Better options would be using find with options rather than find_by_sql !!

Comment: @SachinR will you elaborate plz..? I just don't get it..!

Comment: @SahilGrover First, I am retrieving all the student_id from students table and then I am calculating their corresponding leaves in a particular month.

Comment: @ph3n0m_aks try something like this   Leave.where(:academic_status => "APPROVED", :warden_status => "APPROVED", :student_id => student_id ...........)

Comment: I have done everything as said by SachinR and you @SahilGrover but then too, my function returns the same value for different function calls in a loop..!

Comment: @please update the question above if you have updated something ...

Comment: @SahilGrover i think the object created in calculate function is being persisted over a different calls to calculate function. Ref. my update.

Answer (score 0):

```
 calculate(operation, column_name, options = {}).
```

or you can refer the [link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-calculate)